# Choosing non-randomly from a column of names and descriptions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `data.frame (df)` which contains a column of student `projects` based on concrete, bridges or water (some include multiple terms), each project is assigned by a `professor` but I need to choose a second marker for that project. So I would like to match a professor's name based on the fact that both their projects contain the words "concrete", "bridges" or "water".

**Condition:**
No-one can mark their own project. Professors may appear as many times as necessary as second markers.

```
df<-data.frame(professor=c("Hellen", "Ben","Ethel", "Jim","Connor", "Juan","Lucy"), project=c("Bridges with stone", "Waterways","Concrete with steel","Structure of concrete bridges","Public health and water","Masonry of bridges","3D concrete"))
```

A potential solution would look like:

```
data.frame(professor=c("Hellen", "Ben","Ethel", "Jim","Connor", "Juan","Lucy"), project=c("Bridges with stone", "Waterways","Concrete with steel","Structure of concrete bridges","Public health and water","Masonry of bridges","3D concrete"),second_Marker=c("Juan","Connor","Jim","Lucy","Ben","Hellen","Ethel"))
```

[image]

Comment: can each prof only be a second marker once?

Comment: Good question. No, they can appear as many times as randomly possible.

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you. I would like to match them based on whether the project that the professor offers has bridges in the title. ie. Hellen and Juan both work on bridges so they can understand each other's project. Whereas Ben works with water and cannot understand Hellen's work so they would not be a good match.

Comment: @RonakShah ouch! That is my mistake, thank you for spotting that - I will correct it in the description.

Comment: @RonakShah the data frame is correct, the picture was wrong, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this -

Extract the `keyword` value from project using `str_extract`, for each `keyword` get a random match which is not the professor's name.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(keyword = tolower(str_extract(project, 
             regex('(concrete|bridges|water)', ignore_case = TRUE)))) %>%
  mutate(second_Marker = map_chr(professor, 
                         ~sample(setdiff(professor, .x), 1))) %>%
  ungroup

#  professor project                       keyword  second_Marker
#  <chr>     <chr>                         <chr>    <chr>        
#1 Hellen    Bridges with stone            bridges  Juan         
#2 Ben       Waterways                     water    Connor       
#3 Ethel     Concrete with steel           concrete Jim          
#4 Jim       Structure of concrete bridges concrete Lucy         
#5 Connor    Public health and water       water    Ben          
#6 Juan      Masonry of bridges            bridges  Hellen       
#7 Lucy      3D concrete                   concrete Ethel
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. my R says  x object 'regex' not found. I'm sure I've seen this error before but can't find anything on google. Have you seen out before?

Comment: `regex` function is available in `stringr` package. Try using `stringr::regex`

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. This works nicely. I realise that not all project titles contain those but something similar, which might appear only once. So that will have its own category. Is it possible do "relax" the constraint and have multiple words fit into the same category. Eg. concrete AND bridges is one category for example?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand but you can use `str_extract_all` to extract all the keywords in a project. `str_extract` would only give one (first) pattern in the output.

Comment: @Ronah Shah, just a quick question: how does your second mutate take into consideration the keywords?

Comment: It does not. The first `group_by` ensures that the data from the same keyword is only passed to `mutate` so we don't have to worry about keywords in the `mutate` step.

Comment: Ronak, thank you very much for the explanation. It works beautifully. I do find that it is not very random with certain professors having many projects to mark which isn't fair. I wonder if I can allocate the project second markers based on how "few" projects the professors have as 1st supervisor. ie. if Hellen supervises many students then she should mark few projects. What do you think?

Comment: I just realised that sometimes only 1 professor does structures but they cannot mark their own project. I have a data.frame of all professors (more than just the ones who offered the projects) and their keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and `stringr`:

### Data:

```
df<-data.frame(professor=c("Hellen", "Ben","Ethel", "Jim","Connor", "Juan","Lucy"), project=c("Bridges with stone", "Waterways","Concrete with steel","Structure of concrete bridges","Public health and water","Masonry of bridges","3D concrete"))
```

### Code:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(project = str_to_lower(project)) %>% 
  mutate(indicator = NA) %>% 
  mutate(indicator = ifelse(str_detect(project,
                                   "water"),
                        "water",
                        indicator)) %>% 
  mutate(indicator = ifelse(str_detect(project,
                                       "bridges"),
                            "bridges",
                            indicator)) %>% 
  mutate(indicator = ifelse(str_detect(project,
                                       "concrete"),
                            "concrete",
                            indicator))


prof <- df2 %>% 
  select(indicator, professor) %>% 
  rename(second_Marker = professor)

left_join(df2,
          prof,
          by = "indicator") %>% 
  filter(professor != second_Marker) %>% 
  group_by(professor, project) %>% 
  slice_sample(n = 1) %>% 
  select(-indicator) %>%
  ungroup()
```

### Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   professor, project [7]
  professor project                       second_Marker
  <chr>     <chr>                         <chr>        
1 Ben       waterways                     Connor       
2 Connor    public health and water       Ben          
3 Ethel     concrete with steel           Lucy         
4 Hellen    bridges with stone            Juan         
5 Jim       structure of concrete bridges Lucy         
6 Juan      masonry of bridges            Hellen       
7 Lucy      3d concrete                   Jim
```

As `slice_sample` is random, you'll get another second marker each time you run the code

### Edit:

Now, if you want a unique category for bridges or concrete, the `|` operator can handle it, with the almost the same code:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(project = str_to_lower(project)) %>% 
  mutate(indicator = NA) %>% 
  mutate(indicator = ifelse(str_detect(project,
                                       "water"),
                            "water",
                            indicator)) %>%
  mutate(indicator = ifelse(str_detect(project,
                                       "concrete") | str_detect(project,
                                                                "bridges"),
                            "concrete_or_bridges",
                            indicator))

prof <- df2 %>% 
  select(indicator, professor) %>% 
  rename(second_Marker = professor)

left_join(df2,
          prof,
          by = "indicator") %>% 
  filter(professor != second_Marker) %>% 
  group_by(professor, project) %>% 
  slice_sample(n = 1) %>% 
  select(-indicator) %>%
  ungroup()
```

When the `project` contains `concrete` OR (`|`) `bridges`, it consideres the project belongs to `concrete_or_bridges` category.

Thus, one possible output:

```
  professor project                       second_Marker
  <chr>     <chr>                         <chr>        
1 Ben       waterways                     Connor       
2 Connor    public health and water       Ben          
3 Ethel     concrete with steel           Lucy         
4 Hellen    bridges with stone            Ethel        
5 Jim       structure of concrete bridges Ethel        
6 Juan      masonry of bridges            Lucy         
7 Lucy      3d concrete                   Juan
```

As you can see, Ethel will be the second marker of Hellen project, even if Ethel project is about concrete and Hellen's about bridges

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your help and solution to this. I like that this is flexible to allow different words into the same category. E.g. bridges AND structures could still be bridges.  What do you think?

Comment: @HCAI I'm not sure to get it. Do you want Bridges AND structures be a category when the two met in the project (ie "structure of concrete bridges" -> new category), or do you want a category when one of the two is met (ie "bridges with stone" or "3d concrete" -> new category)?

Comment: Thanks, I mean that if it has structures or bridges then it is the same category

Comment: @HCAI Please see the edit.